# How can one retrieves User's role when logged in?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

I have successfully logged in a user with `Parse.User.logIn(username,password)`. Now my WebApp needs to show a page based on the user's role.

Is this possible on the client side?
Can I get the user's role with `Parse.User` ?

Thank you ❤️

Comment: I don't really know about parse but Normally when user is successfully logged in, you can send user role back to the front-end addition to the token, you can test the role and send user to different webpages, `if(user.role === 'important '){ send.to('importantpage')} else{ send.to('normal page')}`

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to just maintain a list of roles on each User. Otherwise you're going to have to query the roles and check if any of them reference your user.